# Getting undefined method `contains_attachment?' when using sunspot_solr for search inside the documents/attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am trying to implement fulltext search inside attachments using sunspot_solr but getting `undefined method contains_attachment?` when running `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`.

I am following this:
https://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/

Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sunspot', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_rails"
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'
gem 'sunspot_cell_jars'
gem 'progress_bar'
```

Need help!!